# Opening a file in C for reading

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have an issue with C programming and would like a huge help from you all.

I'm supposed to write a console application that is going to manage human resources. The code below is supposed to check if the *userlist.txt* file exists and if so it reads from it. The code compiles and links successfully but I get a segmentation fault when I execute it.

```
bool userListAvailable() {
  bool userListExist = false;
  struct user_details userlist[number_of_employee];
  FILE *userListFile=fopen("userlist.txt", "w");
  if (!(userListFile == NULL)) {
    fread(userlist, sizeof (userlist), 1, userListFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (userlist); ++i) {
        if (strstr(userlist[i].email, "@") != NULL) {
            userListExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
  }
  fclose(userListFile);
  return userListExist;
}
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I tried several other almost similar questions , but it was in vain.

Comment: You cannot read from a file opened as `"w"` (write-only)

Comment: Indentation would help us. BTW `if (!(userListFile == NULL)) {` should be `if (userListFile != NULL) {`

Comment: @M.M - Good point

Comment: Furthering that, the result of the `fread` goes unchecked; a violation of [Spencer's Sixth Commandment.](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html).

Comment: I tried all the options mentioned above, and using gdb I keep getting the same issue. when I do  print userListFile I get this $1 = (FILE *) 0x0

Comment: @M.M I also tried using "w+" following this document http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm.

Comment: You also never check if `fread(userlist, sizeof (userlist), 1, userListFile);` actually reads anything, but you still call `strstr()` on potentially uninitialized memory.  That will lead to a `SIGSEGV` rather quickly.

Comment: `fclose(userListFile);` should be inside the  `if (!(userListFile == NULL))` clause. Otherwise you call `fclose(userListFile)`  with userListFile being `NULL` which is undefined behaviour (you'll most likely get a segfault, and maybe this is even the cause of your problem).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the discussion at the top

`for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(userlist); ++i) {`

Is most likely wrong, as you want to read `number_of_employee` rather than the number of bytes in your buffer.

Most likely you'd get a segfault at `userlist[i]` as `sizeof(userlist)` is probably a larger number than `number_of_employee`

Comment: should be `sizeof userlist / sizeof *userlist`

Comment: the number_of_employee I set it like this number_of_employee = (int) pow(2, 100);

Comment: @DavidNIWEWE You don't have `1267650600228229401496703205376` employees or RAM to store that big of an array.

Comment: @DavidNIWEWE That's ~1.8e20 times the Earth's population. Are you doing HR for an intergalactic empire?

Comment: @Mikhail Thank you so much, I actually reduced the number_of_employee=(int) pow (2,10) and it worked nicely. Thank you, thank you. You're a life safer. I have set a number that big just to see the power of C. and hooraaayy!

Comment: @molbdnilo hahahaha good one!! I was just trying to stress C indeed. I had even tried to use size_t just to see the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the userlist.txt file exists, You can check it using Open.
Open will return the new file descriptor, or -1 if an error occurred (in which case, errno is set appropriately). Here is the man http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html
Then if the FD (file descriptor) than open returned is different that -1, it means that the file exist and that you succesfully opened it, so you can read it using the FD.